# Random error "Unexpected token in JSON"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, syntax-error

I'm using AngularJS to develop a website, and I'm doing multiple selects in an API to list similar products, but I'm having troubles to list the items because in some cases, randomly, JSON returns: *SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 2512*. The code I have is:

```
$timeout(function() {
            console.log(id_filtroParecido);
            Conecta('get','getProdutosFiltrados', id_filtroParecido).then(function(val) {
                vm.respostaListaParecidos = val;
            });
        }, 100);
```

In the above code, the function Conecta make a search in the DB and returns a JSON. But its unpredictable as in it works sometimes, but fails other times.

Here an example of the JSON i receive and works fine:

```
[{"id_produto":"1","nome_produto":"Epson Impressora 1","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"1","sob_encomenda_produto":"1","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 1</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Impressora a Raio Lazer</p>","tags_produto":"Impressora, Lazer, Epson","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"1-epson-impressora-1","imagem_principal":"288738cdb4b99c10e877a25089d46074.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"43","nome_produto_tamanho":"7- Padr\u00e3o","valor_produto_tamanho":"1500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"200","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"N\u00e3o","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]},{"id_produto":"2","nome_produto":"Impressora Epson 2","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"0","sob_encomenda_produto":"0","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 2</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es t&eacute;cnicas da impressora Epson 2</p>","tags_produto":"","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"2-impressora-epson-2","imagem_principal":"c38bf5d110a03964740266c3ee43e123.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"42","nome_produto_tamanho":"5-\u00danico","valor_produto_tamanho":"500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"199","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"Sim","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]}]
```

Here an example of JSON that sometimes return error, sometimes dont:

```
[{"id_produto":"6","nome_produto":"HP G42-214BR","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"1","sob_encomenda_produto":"0","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do note HP</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es do note JP</p>","tags_produto":"tag1, tag2, tag3","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"6-hp-g42-214br","imagem_principal":"87c2ee41b5b8fc13db9a3c2db655667b.png","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"54","nome_produto_tamanho":"1- Padr\u00e3o","valor_produto_tamanho":"1500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"352","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"9","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"Ou em 10x de R$150.00","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]},{"id_produto":"1","nome_produto":"Epson Impressora 1","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"1","sob_encomenda_produto":"1","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 1</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Impressora a Raio Lazer</p>","tags_produto":"Impressora, Lazer, Epson","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"1-epson-impressora-1","imagem_principal":"288738cdb4b99c10e877a25089d46074.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"43","nome_produto_tamanho":"7- Padr\u00e3o","valor_produto_tamanho":"1500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"200","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"N\u00e3o","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]},{"id_produto":"2","nome_produto":"Impressora Epson 2","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"0","sob_encomenda_produto":"0","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 2</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es t&eacute;cnicas da impressora Epson 2</p>","tags_produto":"","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"2-impressora-epson-2","imagem_principal":"c38bf5d110a03964740266c3ee43e123.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"42","nome_produto_tamanho":"5-\u00danico","valor_produto_tamanho":"500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"199","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"Sim","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]}]
```

And gere an example of JSON that always return error:

```
[{"id_produto":"1","nome_produto":"Epson Impressora 1","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"1","sob_encomenda_produto":"1","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 1</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Impressora a Raio Lazer</p>","tags_produto":"Impressora, Lazer, Epson","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"1-epson-impressora-1","imagem_principal":"288738cdb4b99c10e877a25089d46074.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"43","nome_produto_tamanho":"7- Padr\u00e3o","valor_produto_tamanho":"1500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"200","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"N\u00e3o","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]},{"id_produto":"2","nome_produto":"Impressora Epson 2","ativo_produto":"1","destaque_produto":"0","sob_encomenda_produto":"0","marcadagua_produto":"0","descricao_produto":"<p>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o da impressora Epson 2</p>","informacao_produto":"<p>Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es t&eacute;cnicas da impressora Epson 2</p>","tags_produto":"","ordem":"1","acessos":"0","marca_produto":"","slug_produto":"2-impressora-epson-2","imagem_principal":"c38bf5d110a03964740266c3ee43e123.jpeg","tamanho":[{"id_produto_tamanho":"42","nome_produto_tamanho":"5-\u00danico","valor_produto_tamanho":"500.00","quantidade_produto_tamanho":"199","comprimento_produto_tamanho":"16","altura_produto_tamanho":"16","largura_produto_tamanho":"16","peso_produto_tamanho":"16","promocao_valor_produto_tamanho":"0.00","parcelamento_produto_tamanho":"Sim","tem_promocao_produto_tamanho":"0"}]}]
```

Obs: I use de same products here, but it is independent of what product is returning

Here my factory code that i use to conect Angular with the PHP:

```
.factory('Conecta', ['$timeout','$q','AppService', function(time, q, Service) {
        return function(acao,api,parametro){
            var deferred = q.defer(); 
            switch(acao) {
                case 'get':
                    Service.apiGET(api,parametro).then(function(response) {      
                        if(response.status == 200){
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        }else{
                            deferred.resolve(null);
                        }
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                break;
            }          
            return deferred.promise;                
        };
    }])
```

Comment: Kind of hard to say given you haven't given a sample of a failing JSON.

Comment: sounds like an invalid stored value breaks the JSON somehow; when that value is among results, it fails.

Comment: You can get sample of your JSON in browser. Open dev. tools pane by pressing F12. Look at Network tab. There are listed all http queries. Here you can catch what returns from server/DB. Each query has tabs request and response. After this you can inspect what is an unexpected token at some position in JSON.

Comment: I have edited my question to put an example of the JSON i get

Comment: Is that JSON an example of code that fails? Because that's what we would need in order to diagnose the error.

Comment: Yes, but some times it fails, some times not

Comment: I would look at the service/API. It may be returning invalid JSON for some parameters. I was able to run the provided JSON through `JSON.parse` and it works every time.

Comment: In my API the JSON also works every time, but not in my code, and the parameters are always de same. Just the fact that i refresh the page make de JSON crash, with the same JSON every time.

Comment: Sidenote: your service has `deferred` antipattern. You already have promise, no reason to use `$q.defer` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes problem may be in that you return not a clear JSON as it said in syntaxes rules and expected by browser cause of Content-type of the response is application/json, but return a string which contains something very like as the JS object.
Here is very roughly diff between `JSON` and `JS object`

`JSON: {"param":"value"}`

`JS object: {param:"value"}`

Note the quotes for the name of the keys. But hard to say what is  the real problem in your code without of JSON that fail.

Comment: I put an example of the JSON i got in my question

Comment: As it was examined by #Mike McCaughan, and no problem found, problem may be in how you sending/processing JSON response. It may occur that you pass a big data which chunked by server, but eagerly parsed by browser. You need to look at your handler and maybe use a streaming JSON parser. Please, check what is processed by the handler, set the console.out(data), copy and make JSON.parse of it, is it successful?

Comment: I ran a few tests and realized that I get the json correctly from my API, and the error occours only when the JSON has just 1 product, if the JSON contain 2 or more products, it will work correctly. I imagine that the problem occours at the moment the browser interprets the JSON, or something like that.

Comment: So, all times your JSON is considered as array of Products ? If yes, then check that it is array whenever you returning one or many Products.
If you returning JSON as set of {ProductID:{}, ProductID:{}} than problem might be in the parser, or in encoding of response and content of JSON, may be. Need to inspect deeper :) Though, you are very close to revealing the problem.

Comment: Yes, the JSON is allways an array of products, and if it have only 1 productID, it will only have 1 json, i will edit my question to put more examples of my JSONs.

Comment: Hmm... It's looks like a not JSON, but array of json objects. Here is problem. You need return real JSON like: `{"products":[{product1}, {product2},..]}` Here json syntax rules http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: @YanPak, `json` is not `object` it's `notation`. Valid JSONs: `"str"`, `false`, `{"key": "val"}`, `[1, 2, 3]` All of these are `real JSON`

Answer (score 0):

All your JSONs are correct.
You can perform

```
JSON.parse('{"kk":11}');
```

for each of them in some `js REPL`(like a browser console) to inspect that fact.

Possible issues:

1. You are tried to parse part of JSON and should load all chunks before.
2. You get wrong JSON, but can't to catch it for a question example for some reasons.

Comment: I receive the JSON from the API exactly like i posted in the question, i'm using CURL to get them, but i'm using a factory to "talk" with the PHP from JS, and in my controller i get error, but in my factory my JSON works fine. I will edit my question to show my factory